# ¿Async await en el controlador o en el modelo?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, mvc, express, asincronismo

estoy practicando asincronía en node.js utilizando el framework express. Mi problema no es de compilación ya que el código funciona, mi problema es no saber si en verdad se está cumpliendo la asincronía. Ejecuté el código de dos formas y en ambas funciona, pero no sé cuál es el correcto.

Código 1 (async await en el modelo):

```
    //Función alojada en el archivo FriendController

                FriendController.deleteFriendById = (req, res) => {
                    const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
                    FriendModel.deleteFriendById(id, (err) => { //llamo al modelo
                        if(err) throw err;
                        else res.send('Usuario borrado');
                    }) 
            }

    //Función alojada en el archivo FriendModel

            FriendModel.deleteFriendById = async (id, callback) => {
                await pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`, callback);
            }
```

Código 2 (async await en el controlador):

```
    //Función alojada en el archivo FriendController

                FriendController.deleteFriendById = async (req, res) => {
                    const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
                    await FriendModel.deleteFriendById(id, (err) => { //llamo al modelo
                        if(err) throw err;
                        else res.send('Usuario borrado');
                    }) 
            }

    //Función alojada en el archivo FriendModel

            FriendModel.deleteFriendById = (id, callback) => {
                pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`, callback);
            }
```

Código 3 (igual que el código 2 pero con cambios):

```
//Función alojada en el archivo FriendController

            FriendController.deleteFriendById = async (req, res) => {
                try {
                    await FriendModel.deleteFriendById(req.params.id);
                    res.send('Usuario borrado');
                } catch (error) {
                    res.send(error);
                } 
            }

//Función alojada en el archivo FriendModel

        FriendModel.deleteFriendById = (id) => {
            pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`);
        }
```

¿Cuál de estos tres es el correcto y por qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ante todo, recuerda que para poder esperar o `await` la resolución de una función asíncrona (como las promesas) lo que sea que estés llamando tiene que devolverte ya sea la promesa o un valor (no hay nada de malo en hacer await de algo que no es una promesa).

Sin embargo, en el enfoque orientado a callbacks, el paradigma es no retornar nada. Las funciones variádicas que soportan ambas modalidades suelen tener un footprint del tipo:

```
 async function variadicFN(argumento, callback) {
    let respuesta = await (otra operación);
    if(!callback) {
      return respuesta;
    } 
    callback(respuesta);
 }
```

Pensemos en un ejemplo bien básico

```
 // entrega el doble del argumento
 async function variadicDoble(argumento, callback) {
   let total = 2*argumento;
   if(!callback) {
      return total;
   } 
   callback(total);
 }
```

Si tú hicieras:

```
 let resultado = variadicDoble(100, (total)=> {
                    // imprime 200
                    console.log( total);
                });
 // imprime undefined
 console.log(resultado);
```

**Nótese que**  `console.log(variadicDoble(100))` no imprime 200. Imprime `Promise {<resolved>: 200}` porque una función asíncrona siempre devuelve una promesa, sin importar si ya la tiene resuelta.

Dado lo anterior, en tu **Código 1** cuando llamas a:

```
   FriendModel.deleteFriendById = async (id, callback) => {
        await pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`, callback);
   };
```

Ese await no está haciendo nada. Es un `await undefined`. (pero da igual, porque el controller tampoco esperaba que le retornaran nada).

En el **Código 2** en tu controller pones:

```
   await FriendModel.deleteFriendById(id, (err) => { //llamo al modelo
                    if(err) throw err;
                    else res.send('Usuario borrado');
   })
```

Ese await está recibiendo la salida de `FriendModel.deleteFriendById` que no retorna nada. O sea, ahí dice  `await undefined`. No está haciendo nada. Si pusieras:

```
   console.log('Antes de borrar');
   await FriendModel.deleteFriendById(id, (err) => { //llamo al modelo
                    if(err) throw err;
                    else console.log('Usuario borrado');
   }) 
   console.log('Después de borrar');
```

Obtendrías

```
  Antes de borrar
  Después de borrar
  Usuario borrado
```

En el código 3:

```
            try {
                await FriendModel.deleteFriendById(req.params.id);
                res.send('Usuario borrado');
              } catch (error) {
                res.send(error);
              }
```

Ahí sí estás parando el flujo hasta que `FriendModel.deleteFriendById` se resuelva. **Peero**:

```
    //Función alojada en el archivo FriendModel
    FriendModel.deleteFriendById = (id) => {
            pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`);
    }
```

No estás retornando, así que tienes de nuevo un `await undefined` que pasa de largo y manda la respuesta. En cambio, tendría que ser

```
    FriendModel.deleteFriendById = (id) => {
       return  pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`);
    }
```

O, si prefieres:

```
    FriendModel.deleteFriendById = async (id) => {
       await  pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`);
       return;
    }
```

Y muchas otras combinaciones.

**A ti te intriga el por qué te funciona de ambas formas**. Yo no veo que estés comprobando eso en tu código. En todos los casos hay uno o más puntos en donde un `await undefined` pasa de largo y nunca llegas a pausar realmente el flujo. Si en este momento te funciona es porque no hay errores entre medio y si le respondes al frontend que todo salió bien, por debajo eso se cumple medio segundo después y, claro, cuando vas a mirar efectivamente se eliminó el registro.

Te recomiendo usar la librería [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) para poner debug statements antes y después de llamar a una función asíncrona, y de paso mete otros statements dentro de ella. Esa librería es como un console.log a todo color, pero además en cada impresión te muestra los milisegundos transcurridos desde la última vez que se ejecutó.

**Dónde poner el async/await**

Respecto a dónde se debiera poner el async/await, en realidad es cosa de opiniones, pero hay un principio, una ley y un paradigma que tener en cuenta.

Pensemos en un escenario donde una persona (BackendRockStar) mantiene la capa de persistencia y otra (FrontendNinja) mantiene los controllers. Lo planteo así porque cuando uno mismo controla las dos cosas asume como obvias cosas que no lo son.

Primero, está el [principio de la mínima sorpresa](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment). FrontendNinja en realidad está haciendo los controllers pero lo suyo no es el backend. Él espera que al hacer:

```
  await <método del modelo>
```

ese await no se resuelva hasta que el modelo haga lo que le pidió (borrar un usuario). Y espera que si invoca la función pasándole un callback,  el modelo invoque el callback pasándole `(err, resultado)`. Si BackendRockstar hace bien su trabajo, FrontendNinja no tendrá que lidiar con un escenario en donde

- el await pase de largo porque el método retorna undefined
- el await no se resuelva nunca
- en vez de tirar una excepción el modelo haga `process.exit(0)`
- invoque con callback y el modelo lo invoque con `(resultado, err)`.

Porque no sabrá cómo debuggear eso. Pero BackendRockstar tampoco está obligado a soportar tanto promesas como callbacks. Aquí hay que tomar en cuenta [la ley de Deméter](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_de_Demeter) y el paradigma [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). Por la primera, FrontendNinja no sabe, no necesita ni quiere saber qué hace BackendRockstar en el modelo. Sólo sabe que hay un contrato que dice:

> puedo invocar la función ya sea:
>
> - pasándole un callback que recibirá `(err, resultado)`
> - omitiendo el callback y poniendo un `await` dentro de un bloque `try/catch`

A su vez, BackendRockstar no tiene idea de qué controllers está implementando el otro. Pero no necesita ni quiere saberlo.

Entre ambos hay un contrato de interfaz. ¿Me pasas un callback? Invoco tu callback con `(err, resultado)`. ¿No me pasas un callback? Te devuelvo una promesa o tiro una excepción. O a lo mejor la promesa tirará una excepción porque en realidad, por la ley de Deméter, yo tampoco tengo idea de lo que hace el driver hacia la BBDD ni quiero saberlo.

Si el contrato de interfaz define que sólo se soporta callbacks o sólo se soporta promesas, está perfecto también. Lo importante es que sea consistente y que, dado cualquier cambio en la lógica del modelo, nada se rompa mientras mantengas el contrato.

Comment: Agradezco todo el tiempo que te tomaste al contestar mi pregunta, y de forma tan detallada. Soy bastante nuevo en informática, espero me sepas disculpar si no comprendo algunos de los conceptos expuestos. Estoy cursando licenciatura en informática y espero algún día llegar a ese punto, se nota que sabes mucho del tema. De momento que me hayas explicado la respuesta me alcanza y sobra.
Una última duda, ¿el pool.query devuelve siempre una promesa?, si estuviera haciendo un select, ¿retornaría la promesa y los datos extraídos de la db?, ¿es recomendable usar 'pg' o 'pg-promise'?

Comment: Toda operación sobre el driver devuelve una promesa que se resuelve con los resultados de la query, de manera que  si `result = await db.query('...')` ese result es un array. No sólo para los select, sino también para los INSERT...RETURNING.  Aunque el driver de pg soporta promesas nativamente, yo voto por pg-promise. Encuentro que pg-promise es una obra de arte. Los [columnset](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) y otros helpers te permiten encapsular y reutilizar a gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Node js es orientado a eventos. Bajo esa premisa yo diría que lo correcto sería donde se ejecuta el evento, es decir en el controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @RichardVízquerPérez, la mejor práctica seria en el controlador.

Ahora viendo tu código, te quería comentar que estas mezclando `async/await`con `callbacks` para manejar la asincronía de NodeJS, y no es lo correcto ya que para manejar la asincronia puedes usar `Callbacks`, `Promise` o `Async/await`. Te comento tus ejemplos:

- Còdigo 1 + Código 2:

---

```
 //Código 2: estas usando 'callbacks' para recibir el dato, no es necesario 'async/await'
 FriendController.deleteFriendById = (req, res) => {
       const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
       FriendModel.deleteFriendById(id, (err) => {
             if(err) throw err;
             else res.send('Usuario borrado');
       }) 
 }

 //Còdigo 1: No te es necesario utilizar 'async/await' porque estas usando 'callback'
 FriendModel.deleteFriendById = (id, callback) => {
       pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`, callback); 
 }
```

- Código 3:

---

```
//Este código es correcto, solo usas 'async/await' para controlar el asincronismo
FriendController.deleteFriendById = async (req, res) => {
      try {
          await FriendModel.deleteFriendById(req.params.id);
          res.send('Usuario borrado');
      } catch (error) {
                res.send(error);
      } 
}

//Función alojada en el archivo FriendModel
FriendModel.deleteFriendById = (id) => {
       return pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`); //Esto devuelve una promesa
}
```

- Còdigo 4 (otra forma de realizar la consulta con promesas):

---

```
//Función alojada en el archivo FriendController
FriendController.deleteFriendById = (req, res) => {
      FriendModel.deleteFriendById(req.params.id)
            .then(data =>{
                res.send('Usuario borrado');
            }) 
            .catch(err =>{
                res.send(error);
            })
}

//Función alojada en el archivo FriendModel
FriendModel.deleteFriendById = (id) => {
       return pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`); //Esto devuelve una promesa
}
```

Si tuvieras dudas sobre Callbacks, Promises y Async/await, busca por el foro que hay mucha documentación para que puedas comprenderlo.

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de analizar y contestar, en serio.
Estoy poniendo en práctica el código 3. Intento un poco evitar las callback y promises porque comparando código, desde mi punto de vista, pareciera entenderse mucho mejor  el async await. Con tu respuesta me quitaste la duda, gracias.

Comment: @BrianHerrera, no hay de que, estamos para intentar ayudar. Pienso como tu,  `async/await` es más entendible pero no siempre podrás usarlo ya que hay librerías que siguen usando `callbacks`. Una cosa, en el código  3 y 4 se me olvido poner un return en el modelo, ya que sin eso no se devolvería la promesa. Que vaya bien y un saludo

Comment: Una última pregunta, en el código 3, la función que está en el FriendModel, ¿no debería también tener el `async/await`?
Así quedaría:
`FriendModel.deleteFriendById = async (id) => {`
       `return await pool.query(`delete from amigos where id = '${id}'`);`
`}`

Comment: Hola @BrianHerrera, pregunta lo que necesites, te responderé cuando pueda. No te haría falta hacer un `async/await` porque la función `pool.query(..)` devuelve una promise que la resolverás en el controlador,  ya que si la resuelves en el modelo al devolverla promise resuelta devuelve otra promise, por lo que no es necesaria. Otro caso seria que tuvieras que hacer alguna transacción o algo mas entonces es posible que si te hiciera falta.

Comment: ¿Cuál es mejor o más recomendable utilizar: el Pool 'pg' o el db de 'pg-promise' ?.. Yo utilizaba el 'pg' para practicar, pero empecé a utilizar el 'pg-promise' porque se hace asincrónico. Pero no sabía que el 'pg' también devuelve una promesa